# Is there a good iPhone app for tracking commercial aircraft?

Tags: landing, commercial-aviation, traffic-pattern

I can see many airplanes circling around to land at KORD. I am wondering if there is a good real-time website or application to track these planes with 30-second accuracy or better. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt it. Sounds likes a terrorist's wet dream, even if it could be used for plane spotters and the like

Comment: Hi Stu, welcome to the site!  This question has already been asked and has several answers which should answer your question.  My own answer on the question describes why the sites don't have real-time data available (it isn't allowed by the FAA unless you have an operational need).  If this doesn't answer your question, please [edit] it with the new info and we will consider reopening your question!

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. I will check out the other question!